# Waiting for feedback from every consumer with RabbitMQ on a topic exchange

Tags: python, .net, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

I have a publisher (using RabbitMQ .NET client) and multiple consumers (using Pika Python module). They are using a single topic exchange and consumers have separate queues. I want to achieve a distributed RPC-style call, which requires me to wait for replies (JSON) before continuing or timeout.

When I publish my message, I need to wait and get replies from “all” of the clients that got my message. (Probably to a single consumer on the publisher side.) I publish my messages with a routing key so I don’t know how many consumers are listening before publishing but I still need to wait arbitrary number of clients.

This is for informing the user that we are processing their request and give a feedback whether their request has been fulfilled completely or not.

Is there a way to achieve this with RabbitMQ? I don’t want to use Broker’s specific RESTful API to get the consumer names / consumer count and wait with a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this task is not possible using AMQP only. I had to use RabbitMQ's API.

Making a GET request to following address: `http://rabbitmq_hostname:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/worker/bindings/source` returns every consumer for the exchange "worker" in the vhost /. (which was encoded as %2F)

Getting the count of consumers with separate queues is simple as:

```
jsonResponse.Where(o => o["destination_type"] == "queue").Count();
```

If I send a message to the topic exchange, I'd know how many responses I should expect.